# Views REST Export not stripping HTML tags and adding extra special characters for links

Tags: views, 8

I created a REST export using Views for taxonomy. But, I am unable to strip

tags from the description. Also, I am getting extra special characters for links.

```
[{"title":"featured 1","header":"learn how to contribute","text":"\u003Cp\u003ELorem ipsum dolor asit Lorem ipsum dolor asitLorem ipsum dolor asitLorem ipsum dolor asit\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n","link":"https:\/\/www.google.com"},{"title":"Featured 2","header":"learn how to contribute","text":null,"link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com"}]
```

How can I strip HTML tags from the description and remove "//" from links in above JSON output?

I checked "**Strip HTML tags**" option for description. Please see image below.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-06-23/modify-rest-export-api-response) it's a thread in drupal forum about how to `Modify REST Export API response structure in Drupal 8`

Comment: I already made the output as raw output and I am getting the result with https:/\/\